# How to prove volume of parallelepiped?

Tags: 3d, volume

Let's say that three consecutive edges of a parallelepiped be **a** , **b** , **c** . Then how to show that volume is = [**a** **b** **c**] 
Or = **a.(b × c)** ?

Also how to prove this  [this](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f13e098bfa30f807fab3a7380a8e2524f0fce410) too?

Comment: see also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped

Comment: Depending on how rigorous you want the proof to be, you need to say what you mean by volume first.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ form the base. Then the area of the base is,

$$|\vec a \times \vec b|$$

The height of the parallelogram is orthogonal to the base, so it is the component of $\vec c$ onto $\vec a \times \vec b$ which is perpendicular to the base,

$$\text{comp}_{\vec a \times \vec b}\vec c=\frac{|c. (\vec a \times \vec b)|}{|\vec a \times \vec b|}$$

Multiplying the two together gives the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

area of base of parallelepiped (parallelogram) = $\mathbf b \times \mathbf c$

the vector $\mathbf b \times \mathbf c$ will be perpendicular to base

therefore:
$$
\begin{align}
\text{volume of parallelopiped} &= \text{area of base} \times \text{height}\\
                              &= (\mathbf b \times \mathbf c) \times A \cos \theta\\
                              &= \mathbf a\cdot(\mathbf b \times \mathbf c)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don't think it's correct _"the vector **b** x **c** will be perpendicular to vector **a**"_

Comment: oh sorry i meant base